# How Can I Display Post Record In Bootstrap Modal In Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I am trying to build a web app with a little feel of mobile app (I am still lazy learning cross-platform frameworks :) ). So I have a page that displays all events posts and I can view each single post by clicking on the a href (my route works perfectly). But what I actually want to achieve is to display each post event IN A BOOTSTRAP MODAL. So that if I use button and I add wire:click to the button (*button type="button" wire:click.prevent="show({{ $event->id }})">), it should bring up the modal and the data passed into it. But unfortunately, it is not working :(. The modal will display but the data is NOT passed :'(

My codes below:

app\Http\Livewire\Events.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Event;

class Events extends Component
{
    public $events;
    public $event;
    public $event_id;
    public $event_title;
    public $event_author;
    public $event_date;
    public $event_time;
    public $event_image;
    public $event_location;
    public $event_map;
    public $event_details;

    public function show($id)
    {
        $this->event  = Event::where('id', $id)->first();

        $this->event_id         = $id;
        $this->event_title      = $event->event_title;
        $this->event_author     = $event->event_author;
        $this->event_date       = $event->event_date;
        $this->event_time       = $event->event_time;
        $this->event_image      = $event->event_image;
        $this->event_location   = $event->event_location;
        $this->event_map        = $event->event_map;
        $this->event_details    = $event->event_details;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->events   = Event::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('livewire.events');
    }
}
```

resources\views\livewire\events.blade.php

```
@section('title', 'Events')
@include('livewire.view-event')

<div class="block pt-1 pb-6">
    <div class="row m-0">
        @if (count($events) > 0)
            @foreach ($events as $event)
                <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                    <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showEventModal" wire:click="show({{ $event->id }})">
                        <div class="card bg-white shadow p-0">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <div class="block mb-05">
                                    <img class="inline rounded mr-05" src="/assets/uploads/images/{{ $event->event_image }}" width="40" height="40">

                                    <span class="elegant font-md">{{ $event->event_title }}</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="block elegant font-sm">
                                    <span class="block"><i class="fas fa-bullhorn mr-05"></i> {{ $event->event_author }}</span>

                                    <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> {{ $event->event_date }} <span class="mx-05">|</span> <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ $event->event_time }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-body p-0">
                                @if (!empty($event->event_image))
                                    <img class="post-img" src="/assets/uploads/images/{{ $event->event_image }}">
                                @else
                                    <img class="post-img" src="/assets/img/no-image.jpg">
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <div class="col-12 text-center">No record found!</div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

resources\views\livewire\view-event.blade.php

```
<div wire:ignore.self id="showEventModal" class="modal fade come-from-modal right" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="showEventModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header white bg-red-dark borderless shadow-sm">
                <a type="button" class="back mr-4 white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span></a>

                <div class="page-title">{{ $event_title }}</div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" name="id" wire:model="event_id">

                <h1>This is {{ $event_id }}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes\web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

use App\Http\Livewire\Main;
use App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard;
use App\Http\Livewire\Events;

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'homepage'])->name('homepage');
    Route::get('/dashboard', Dashboard::class)->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/events', Events::class)->name('events');
});
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I even changed the fade in transition effect of bootstrap modal to open from right like mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the show method to this and check

```
public function show($id)
{
    $this->event  = Event::where('id', $id)->first();

    $this->event_id         = $id;
    $this->event_title      = $this->event->event_title;
    $this->event_author     = $this->event->event_author;
    $this->event_date       = $this->event->event_date;
    $this->event_time       = $this->event->event_time;
    $this->event_image      = $this->event->event_image;
    $this->event_location   = $this->event->event_location;
    $this->event_map        = $this->event->event_map;
    $this->event_details    = $this->event->event_details;
}
```